# MVEL: how to keep java.lang.* classes out of expressions?

Tags: mvel

I'm trying to sandbox MVEL expression evaluation. Unfortunately, by default MVEL includes all java.lang.* classes in the expression language, so a user could call "Runtime.exit()" and kill the whole system.

How can I exclude all classes that I haven't explicitly added with addImport()?

I haven't been able to make heads or tails of the VariableResolvers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I known this is not supported.

I faced this need some time ago on a project of my company. We had to change MVEL quite a bit to introduce a way to configure a custom policy to control access to types and methods.
The problem is that you can also access any class by its fully qualified name, so it was not just a matter of removing the default imports.
Unfortunately I don't own the code to make it available.

Comment: This is too bad. I really like MVEL.

Answer (score 1):

```
ParserContext ctx = new ParserContext();

ctx.addImport("System", String.class);
ctx.addImport("Runtime", String.class);
```

Comment: Your answer is in danger of deletion.  You really need to explain what's happening here and how this answers the question posed.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using AspectJ to constrain these calls from MVEL?

Comment: Not sure how this helps? Implements some kind of security sandbox?